# Problem running ev3dev on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lego-mindstorms-ev3

When I try to run the program on the ev3 brick I keep getting this error:

> Starting: brickrun --directory="/home/robot/maybe" "/home/robot/maybe/main.py"
> Starting program failed: Failed to execute child process "/home/robot/maybe/main.py" (Permission denied)
> Exited with error code 1.

I tried to look this issue up on multiple websites with no luck

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387964/997587

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my script didn't start with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, adding this to the beginning solved the issue.